# Steps to create a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to store procedure in microsoft sql server which produce 30 million records.
I need to create a view on top of the stored procedure. Is it possible to create a view?

If yes could you please share the sample query to create that view?

Comment: No, you cannot. It's possible that the entire stored procedure could instead have been implemented as a view itself but you cannot call an existing SP from a view. We have no way to judge of course since you've not shown us any code.

Comment: tag RDBMS  correctly.MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... .

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure is something which holds the implementation methodology. View Can be created on top of a table.

We cannot create a view on top of a stored procedure by yes we can create a temporary/global temp table in SQL Server.

example:

```
drop table if exists #result;    
create table #result                           
(Source varchar(50),PatientID varchar(100))          
insert into #result
exec sp_procedurename parameter=value with recompile;
```

Comment: There's no need to @ mention the OP. Question askers are automatically notified of all answers to their question.